# How to ensure a string length in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the proper way to ensure a string length in Ruby? The string is multi-byte (UTF8). The strings inputted can be either too short, exactly right, or too long. It would need respectively padding, nothing and slicing.

I can get there in two steps:

```
def ensure_length(str, length)
  str.ljust(length).slice(0, length)
end
```

Is there a single method for this? And if it needs in two steps, what order is best: ljust then slice or vice versa, and why?

Comment: You don't need _both_ steps for any string. It's either one of them or neither (if length is exactly right)

Comment: There is no single method. As for the order - tomayto, tomahto.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you either need both methods or a conditional to handle arbitrary strings.

Comment: @Stefan: yep, I was hinting at conditional.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, why use conditional here, it does the same, but it's uglier and more verbose.

Comment: `sprintf('%1$-*2$.*2$s', str, length)` would work ;-)

Comment: @ndn: verbose is not always bad. Take a look at this for example. It probably conveys the intent better: https://pastebin.com/PwCf25Nw. Or not. Matter of taste. :)

Comment: I usually try to avoid conditional branching ...

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, me too, usually. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, one reads *"pad it with spaces, slice it to 5 characters"*. The other one reads *"If exactly 5 characters long, do nothing. If less than 5 characters long, pad it with spaces that much. If longer than 5 - slice it to 5."* Now which one would you use to explain this to a human being? Programmers reading your code are humans.

Comment: @ndn me reading the terser code: _"WTF!? Why do you pad it with spaces just to ... oh, I see, never mind"_

Comment: @ndn: exactly my point. Your "worse" description __is__ the actual business logic here. Today I think it's a better one.

Comment: @Stefan, then you are in the camp that thinks the `ljust` and `slice` should be swapped, but the point still stands.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find your code very readable. If it does what you want it to, why care about using one method instead of 2?

Comment: @EricDuminil, if there was one method that did that specifically (instead of using something in a very convoluted way just with the idea being *"it's one method"*), I would agree one should use the intended method. For example, consider `'foo'.split('')` vs `'foo'.chars`. Both are very readable, yet one is intended exactly for that purpose. It's very easy to reinvent the wheel if the wheel is small enough.

Comment: @EricDuminil, like ndn says: I was wondering if I missed an important piece, method or concept. It seemed like a common enough case that StdLib would cover. I would think there might be a much simpler. and core method.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you are correct. Adding conditionals might speed up stuff (though I doubt that, and would really need to benchmark, if performance were a concern; it is not). But it makes it less readable IMO. And a lot easier to introduce bugs in: it does not convey the purpuse as clear as a dedicated oneliner or method would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 p "%-10.10s" % "abcdabcdabcd"
```

In which the first -10 pads the string to 10 like `ljust` and the second 10 is the max number of characters. Documented under [sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Comment: Nice, I never thought about mixing formats that way.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking for; And it works fine with UTF8: `"%-2.2s" % "王李张" #=> "王李"`.

Answer (score 2):

Is not really better than your version, just an alternative:

```
'foo'[0...5].ljust(5)
#=> "foo  "
'foobar'[0...5].ljust(5)
#=> "fooba"
```

Or as a method:

```
def ensure_length(str, length)
  str[0...length].ljust(length)
end
```